# How do I obtain latitude and logitude coordinates from synoptic weather charts

Tags: image-processing, pixel, latitude-longitude, coordinate-transformation, map-projections

I have collection of images of synoptic weather charts downloaded from Bureau of Meteorology (BoM) (example  [link](http://www.bom.gov.au/cgi-bin/charts/charts.view.pl?idcode=IDX0102&file=IDX0102.202001010000.gif)) which is in GIF format. I'm interested in obtaining the lat lon coordinates of cold fronts (thick black lines with triangles). My idea is: First get the pixel coordinates of the cold fronts.
After obtaining the pixel coordinates, get the lat lon coordinates based on map projection type. BoM [website](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/austmaps/about-rain-maps.shtml) mentions that the map projection type is Lambert Conformal Conic (LCC) projection. How can I speed up obtaining the pixel coordinates? And how to get the exact lat lon coordinates?

First, I approached extracting pixel coordinates in two ways:

1. Manual:- Obtain the pixel coordinates using the *ginput* function of MATLAB where with the help of mouse cursor I got the pixel coordinates.
2. Image processing:- Converted the image into Binary and used edge and boundary detection. **But in some cases this is not working properly.**
   `% CODE IMAGE PROCESSING%`
   `img = imread('IDX0102.201501010000.gif');`
   `binaryImage = imbinarize(img, 'adaptive');`
   `edgeImage = edge(binaryImage, 'Canny');`
   `BW2 = bwareaopen(img,3000);`
   `contourData = bwboundaries(edgeImage);`

For obtaining lat lon coordinates based on LCC,
I tried in MATLAB using *pix2latlon* function and also in python using the *pyproj*. None of them gives the expected results. How do I approach this problem?